# NLP word processing and dataframe unpivot for word cloud

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe that contains only two columns, the ['content_ID'] and ['content'] and I would like to transform it into another dataframe that contains an additional column that tokenizes the content. Any clues on that? Thanks in advance.

```
df = {'content_ID':  ['id_A', 'id_B'],
              'content': ['eating apple', 'i love eat fruits and orange']
                }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

After transformation:

```
|content_ID |content    |word|
|id_A   |eating apple   |eat|
|id_A   |eating apple   |apple|
|id_B   |I love eat fruits and orange   |i|
|id_B   |I love eat fruits and orange   |love|
|id_B   |I love eat fruits and orange   |eat|
|id_B   |I love eat fruits and orange   |fruit|
|id_B   |I love eat fruits and orange   |and|
|id_B   |I love eat fruits and orange   |orange|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to tokenize, you can do it by `str.split`. Then, by using explode you can flatten the list of tokens:

```
df['tokens'] = df['content'].str.split()
df = df.explode('tokens').reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is output if you print df:

```
  content_ID                       content  tokens
0       id_A                  eating apple  eating
1       id_A                  eating apple   apple
2       id_B  i love eat fruits and orange       i
3       id_B  i love eat fruits and orange    love
4       id_B  i love eat fruits and orange     eat
5       id_B  i love eat fruits and orange  fruits
6       id_B  i love eat fruits and orange     and
7       id_B  i love eat fruits and orange  orange
```